# VB Webpage loads previous page data instead

Tags: vb.net, url, master-pages, html

When I am adding a new page that loads all the data from the master page, it is loading all the data from the last page instead of the page it is linking too. I'm quite new to the VB scene so the error may be very simplistic.

```
Once you logon it doesn't redirect you it just leaves you on the logon page. But then when I click on the next page via my navigation menu the page stays the same. 

This link may help understand the problem as I thought this was why it wasn't taking me to the correct page:
http://localhost:50954/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2faccount%2freview

The page I'm trying to get to is http//:...../account/review (It is an intranet web page). 

**Here is the code for my master page!**

<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="SpellingBee.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Spelling Bee</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    Spelling Bee
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <% If Session.Item("User") <> Nothing Then%>
                Hello:
                <%= Session.Item("User") %>
                <% Else%>
                <a id="A2" href="/account/login" runat="server">Logon</a>
                <% End If%>
            </div>
            <div class="menu" style="clear: left;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="~/" runat="server">Home</a></li>
                    <% If Session.Item("User Type") = "Teacher" Then%>
                    <li><a href="/account/review" runat="server">Review Score</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/account/admin" runat="server">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/account/test" runat="server">Create a Test</a></li>
                    <%ElseIf Session.Item("User Type") = "Pupil" Then%>
                    <li><a href="/test" runat="server">Take a Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pupil/peview" runat="server">Review Scores</a></li>
                    <% End If%>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

            <h1 style="position: absolute">Developing Your Literature Skills</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


**Here is the code from the page it won't load!**

<%@ Page Title="Review Pupil Scores" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
 CodeBehind="Review.aspx.vb" Inherits="SpellingBee.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2 style = "clear:both">
 Review Youre Pupils Scores!
 </h2>  
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PupilForename" HeaderText="PupilForename" 
                SortExpression="PupilForename" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PupilSurname" HeaderText="PupilSurname" 
                SortExpression="PupilSurname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentIDNumber" HeaderText="StudentIDNumber" 
                SortExpression="StudentIDNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TeacherID" HeaderText="TeacherID" 
                InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="TeacherID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubjectName" HeaderText="SubjectName" 
                SortExpression="SubjectName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassID" HeaderText="ClassID" InsertVisible="False" 
                SortExpression="ClassID" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Pupil.PupilForename, Pupil.PupilSurname, Pupil.StudentIDNumber, Teacher.TeacherID, Subject.SubjectName, Class.ClassID FROM (((Pupil INNER JOIN Class ON Pupil.ClassID = Class.ClassID) INNER JOIN Teacher ON Class.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID) INNER JOIN Subject ON Class.SubjectID = Subject.SubjectID)">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>


**And here is the code from the logon page that I navigate from once logged in!**

<%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="SpellingBee.Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2 style="clear: both">
        Log In
    </h2>

    <fieldset class="login">
        <legend>Log In</legend>
        <p>

            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="LoginList" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Teacher"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Pupil</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
</asp:Content>
```

This is part of my AS college work and I'm stuck! Any help is greatly appreciated! Sorry if it's vauge or hard to read from!

Comment: @ What is the page transfer .Are you using Server.Transfer,Response.Redirect

Comment: I'm not (Like I said im very new to this type of vb code. But when i click on the logon button from my homepage it akes me there so i assumed that the same way i created my logon page would work for creating this page. Is there any section of code you'd like to see that I haven't given? Sorry for being so vauge im an amatuer!

Comment: you said you had button.What is the Button_click  in the code behind.I hope pasting the codebehind might be a good idea